# Freshly cloned mirrored drive with Acronis true image and rsync wrongly detects changed files, windows rsync 3.0.7 cygwin windows

Tags: windows, rsync, cygwin, mirroring, acronis

Is there a way to help rsync better detect that files are identical? I did a fresh full disk "clone" mirror with Acronis TrueImage and after did an rsync to test and it detected a bunch of files as changed etc. I was copying from C drive, ie Desktop or Documents to F: drive/backup.
I used:

```
rsync -avz --delete --chmod=ugo=rwX --modify-window=2  ...
```

In rsync of eclipse workspace it started detecting a bunch of .metadata etc, I killed it before it finished.

On my Documents folder it seemed to go through listing a bunch of directories, so maybe its just listing directories and not really detecting files? But usually when rsync detects that source and destination really are identical it simply exits without outputting anything at all after displaying it usual "sending incremental file list"...  Which is exactly what happened the SECOND time I ran the rsync on the Documents folder, which I'm sure was IDENTICAL already after my successful Acronis CLONE of my entire drive.

Is this a known problem with rsync on Windows? Is there a solution or better command-line parameters I can use?

Comment: hm maybe its issue with --chmod=ugo=rwX seems that may want to change permission on files copied over... will try without that

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I found the ticket. Drop the --chmod=ugo=rwX 
which of course means later on when trying to access the backups one might get permission denied due to windows NTFS ACL etc but I assume if viewing it on Linux that Linux's ntfs mount tools will ignore that junk and not care. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong on that.

Anyway its still a bit baffling why destination permissions ie my F drive wouldn't have been identical to the source file permissions after an actual FULL CLONE of drive with Acronis TrueImage. But I guess it is possible that once I BOOTED windows that it somehow changed around file permissions on the F: drive which was a CLONE of C drive. So if Windows "did change" permissions somehow on the F: drive clone of C, then it would make sense rsync's chmod=ugo=rwX would detect that and then apply permissions change.

I decided to drop --chmod argument and instead use --no-p --no-g --no-o
With those three I have rsync ignore permissions, group, owner. And it seems to have done the trick, no more long list of detected changed files on the recently acronis trueimage cloned data.